# java JOGL and similar resources

Tags: java, .net, frameworks, 3d

just joined this awesome site…
Ive recently been working in XNA on C#, making a library for that framework.

Ive gotten interested in java at was going to try making a similar library for java.

Thats when the problem arrived, there doesnt seem to be a standard 3d renderer on it.

Ive heard of [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), but it seemed to be discontinued (project inactive), and i prefet high level anyway,

Then I saw [jMonkey](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) and espresso 3D, but both seemed less efficient and less pretty then directx.

[JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) discouraged me by saying that its for rich internet content.

My question is, which out of these are optimal. What is the technical difference between OpenGL and DirectX, are jMonkey and co. Actuallh effective? And if not is there a framework similar to XNA for java?
I only ask you name some and point me in the right direction, as this got me a bit confused after the 1 way .NET xD.

Also, as this is my first post here, feel free to correct any mistaked I may have made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think jmonkeyengine or jogl are probably the best choices, but it really depends on what your doing. Jogl looks like its still going but is now part of a fuller set of libraries, jogamp, which covers sound and gpgpu programming as well as graphics.

http://jogamp.org/

Jogl is essentially a java wrapper around OpenGL, so will be low level and require to write shader code in order to do anything modern. Jmonkeyengine is probably more the sort of thing you're after since it comes with a lot of prepackaged functionality (including its own IDE).

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the jogamp link! I realize it's low level though, which was my main problem with it, are there any other alternatives? (Just making sure I haven't missed anything)

Answer (score 1):

The real *standard* 3D API for Java -- in the sense that it's the one that Sun once considered "official" -- is [Java3D](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html), which is a scene graph API, something like Open Inventor. I never liked it much, and the level of support these days is pretty low. But it's worth considering, if only for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it too, but it seems like a low level library collection, rather then a full framework. There may be more frameworks based on it, so I'll look into that.

Comment: @Shingetsu -- "Low level" is relative -- I always considered Java3D too high level for my needs :)

Comment: @"Ernest Friedman-Hill" what I mean by this is that, compared to "high level frameworks", it does not automate most actions. For example, relatively to DirectX API for C++, XNA on VC# can be considered very high level. At the same time, DirectX API for C++ can be considered high level as opposed to manually drawing each pixel etc. In no way do I mean that it's not effective.